Why is Y-K-V-K which denotes mercy, more strict than saying Elokim which denotes justice?
Kabbalistically speaking, the name Elokim denotes strict justice, while the name Y-K-V-K denotes mercy. If this is the case, then why are we more strict not to say Hashem's name of mercy outside the Beis HaMikdash, but we often say Elokim outside? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Because Elokim is a "lower"name in kabbalistic terms that denotes "powers" (there are "Elokim Acherim" for example, but not, chas v'Shalom "YKVKim Acherim")

First of all, these names are not defined only by judgement and mercy, there are other definitions, such as:
YKVK- היה הווה ויהיה (infinite/eternal),
Elokim- All powerful… etc…
-all among many other meanings to the names whether known or unknown to us.
However, even with just the meaning you brought, I think it’s clear that mercy is actually the greater trait.
One way we see this is that Hashems right hand is Mercy and his left is judgement, and in Judaism there is always an importance to the right hand over the left, like it says in Tehillim (118:15) “Yemin Hashem oseh chayil”.
We also say in davening “asei lemaan yeminecha”.
The Arizal (Ohr Tzaddikim 2:63)
Says to give charity with the right hand. This is based on a medrash (Devarim rabba) that says that charity and Torah are in Hashems right hand.
This is in addition to all other mitzvos we do with the right, of which there are many.
On a more theological level though, mercy has always been the idea that was a revelation. Idol worshippers never had a concept of mercy. Their relationship to their deities was one of sacrifice and punishment. That was and still is the basic idea of a ruler, to exercise power (Elokim).
This is indeed why the Torah refers to other “gods” as elokim, because in terms of power and might, they share that mentality with Hashem.
It’s YKVK that differentiates Hashem from other gods. And as Rav Nachman writes (Likutei Moharan I:64), this world was created so Hashem can show his mercy.
Mercy in this context though is not merely the mercy humans display, like when you feel bad for someone so you give them something to make them feel better. Mercy as it pertains to Hashem is so great that it overrides Hashems own Godly judgement. But more importantly, it exhibits Hashems supreme control over the universe. Only a being with infinite knowledge, who exists outside of time and space can make a proper decision to override judgement. Who else can say in the grand scheme of things that in this situation the rules of the world need not apply? Surely not an idol who’s specialized “power” is over the sun or moon or water and knows nothing outside of that… The answer of course is only the Grand Schemer himself.
So essentially, to be able to enact mercy, really means that Hashems not just powerful but he’s the grand Schemer, and by definition overrides the Elokim part of Hashem.

+1 This may be relevant to the concept of "Asei Docheh Lo Ta'asei" - see Ramban Parashat Yitro who explains the concept along similar lines.

@Chani got a link?
